# Conditional styling in Pandoc/LaTeX/Docx

Tags: pandoc

I have a document (in this case a resume) that is built using pandoc and make.  I produce different versions of my document based on parameters I pass to make.  The content of the resume is pieced together from fragments of Markdown that are processed to produce LaTeX on the way to PDF.

What I'd like to be able to do is annotate my fragments somehow to allow them to get emphasis if their type matches what I want to emphasise.  Is there a way to conditionally control the styling of the document somehow?

Here's the gist of the Makefile to give some context:

```
build_type ?= shortarch
role_type ?= arch

LONGCOMBINED = ./work/9999.work.combined.md ./work/2019.sportsbet.md ./work/2018.telstra.md ./work/2017.liberty.md <a bunch more files>

SHORTCOMBINED = ./work/9999.work.combined.md ./work/2019.sportsbet.md ./work/2018.telstra.md ./work/2017.liberty.md <a bunch more files>

<snip . . .>

ifeq ($(build_type),shortarch)

work = $(SHORTARCH)
role_type = arch

else ifeq ($(build_type),shorteng)

work = $(SHORTENG)
role_type = eng

else ifeq ($(build_type),longarch)

<snip . . .>

else
    @echo 'wuuhhhh?'
endif

edu = $(shell ls ./edu/* | sort -r | head -n 6)
summary=./summary.$(role_type).md
src= metadata.yaml $(summary) $(work) $(edu) ./memberships.md  ./pub.md  ./skills.$(role_type).md  ./interests.md
date=$(shell date --iso-8601)
output=./build/andrew_matthews.$(build_type).$(date)
pandoc_args=-f markdown+smart+yaml_metadata_block --pdf-engine=xelatex

.PHONY: all prep clean

all: prep $(output).pdf $(output).docx $(output).txt

prep:
    @echo "building a $(build_type) resume"
    mkdir -p build

clean:
    rm -f ./build/*

$(output).docx: $(src)
    pandoc -o $@ $(pandoc_args) $^

$(output).pdf: $(src)
    pandoc -o $@ $(pandoc_args) $^

$(output).txt: $(src)
    pandoc -o $@ $(pandoc_args) $^

letters:
    pandoc --template=letters/template-letter.tex  $(pandoc_args) letters/letter1.md -o build/letter1.pdf
```

An entry looks like this:

```
### [UniSuper](http://www.unisuper.com.au)

_Technology Architect and Strategist_ - 2011 to 2017

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur pellentesque vehicula orci ornare fringilla. Aenean sagittis congue sapien. Vestibulum tortor nulla, blandit viverra neque luctus, finibus dapibus mauris. Proin egestas quam ex, ac rutrum nibh iaculis eu. Praesent euismod sagittis odio ac convallis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin semper, erat venenatis consectetur blandit, arcu ex auctor purus, et porta nisi nulla in magna. Donec lobortis tempus ligula ac eleifend. Phasellus purus ipsum, hendrerit vel massa et, commodo suscipit tortor. Aenean sed tristique ligula. Fusce sit amet auctor ex, ut suscipit nulla. Fusce auctor turpis in arcu luctus eleifend vitae non augue.

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
- Donec gravida ante vitae leo vestibulum, ac condimentum erat venenatis.
- Sed rutrum augue vitae nunc rhoncus egestas.
- Suspendisse dapibus tellus eget turpis posuere, et tempor metus efficitur.
- Phasellus interdum odio quis dolor scelerisque mattis.

Skills: _Technical Leadership, Enterprise Architecture, Governance, Strategy, Digital Transformation, etc . . .  _
```

So, depending on whether I am producing a resume that emphasises this kind of role, I might want to grey this out, or shrink or indent it somehow.  The issue is that while some of the Pandoc approaches work OK with docx, I am targeting LaTeX primarily, so I would prefer something that will work with any output format.

Comment: This seems to be a question purely about pandoc, so it is off-topic on this site.  Please ask on https://stackoverflow.com/ instead.

Comment: will do, although it's kind of about how to inject LaTeX into the intermediate model.  Does that still count?

Comment: Hm, not really.  Your problem is on the pandoc end of the LaTeX output.  What you want can probably be done using [pandoc Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) but that is clearly off-topic here, sorry.